# bool value isnt changing in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have the following code :

```
bool hasGoneDown = TRUE;

NSLog(@"%d", hasGoneDown);
    if(y > 700 && hasGoneDown == TRUE){
        [_game addToScore:600];

        hasGoneDown = FALSE;
    }

    if(y < 700){
        NSLog(@"we are IN : %d", hasGoneDown);
        hasGoneDown = TRUE;
    }
```

but for some reason the bool value does NOT change at all even when the conditions are set in the if statements, its always 1!

so what am I doing wrong?

**MORE INFO**

here is more info on what is being done there. 
this is a game, and technically there is a character jumping, and `y` var represents the y axis, so when the character jumps higher than 700, it should do certain stuff... the code above is being called constantly through out the game, but the value for the bool does NOT change AT ALL!

Comment: `y` is the y axis of the game, so technically I am checking to see when the character goes higher than 700, I want to do certain stuff

Comment: we need more information of how your program works.

Comment: added some info in the question, but if you need anything specific please ask!

Comment: Is the line `bool hasGoneDown = TRUE;` in the same method/function as the rest of the code you've shown? If so, the variable can never be false in one of your log statements. In your first log, the variable has just been initialized to true. It is only set to false in your first if-statement, but in that case, the second log is never executed (because the first and second if-statement cannot simultaneously be true).

Comment: hey, thanks, I just got the problem :) I was initializing the bool inside the method so you are right :) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool hasGoneDown = TRUE;

NSLog(@"%d", hasGoneDown);
    if(y > 700 && hasGoneDown == TRUE){
        [_game addToScore:600];

        hasGoneDown = FALSE;
    }

    if(y < 700){
        NSLog(@"we are IN : %d", hasGoneDown);
        hasGoneDown = TRUE;
    }
```

If the whole code is in a function, it would always be true as you initialized it to be true whenever the function is being run.. I hope `bool hasGoneDown = True` is declared somewhere else as a global variable.. And your coditions.. I believe a more "tidy" version of your code is as follows:

```
if(y >= 700 && hasGoneDown == TRUE)
{
    [_game addToScore:600];

     hasGoneDown = FALSE;
}

else{
      NSLog(@"we are IN : %d", hasGoneDown);
      hasGoneDown = TRUE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, do not use "TRUE" and "FALSE".  Use "YES" and "NO".  Secondly you may have a problem with your logic.  It's possible you may want to use a single "if/else" statement rather than two "if" statements.  You'll have to evaluate that for yourself.

```
if(y > 700 && hasGoneDown == YES){
    [_game addToScore:600];

    hasGoneDown = NO;
}

if (y < 700){
    NSLog(@"we are IN : %d", hasGoneDown);
    hasGoneDown = NO;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, the original code snippet appears to be using the (C++) `bool` type, not the Obj-C BOOL. In that case, `true`/`false` are appropriate, but the lowercase versions are the real ones.